# getArgument of NSInvocation of current method always returns null

Tags: objective-c, null, nsinvocation

I want to get the name of the arguments of the current function I am in so that I can prepare loading that object from the filesystem if it's not present on the current instance. (for instance if [foo dictTest] is not available I want to load it's prior saved plist version into exactly that ivar)

I want to find the file by providing the ivar name that I provided as an argument to the current function.

This is the function code:

```
-(NSDictionary*)getCachedDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict{

    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd]];
    NSString * firstArgument = nil;
    [invocation getArgument:&firstArgument atIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"Trying to get the objects ivar %@",firstArgument);

    // right now during testing return nil
    return nil;
   }
```

As soon as the code reaches the NSLog I am getting a null value from firstArgument.

Why is that? Could it be possible that I would have to wait for the complete invocation of that current method I am in or is it actually better to create a proxy function that implicitly calls my class method via an invocation that eats the ivar name provided by setArgument so that I can use that argument string like I want?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S.: In this particular example I do not want to use KVC to identify the ivar and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood the `NSInvocation` API.  `+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]` creates a new `NSInvocation` that is keyed to accept arguments of the types defined by the method signature.  It does *not* return an `NSInvocation` that corresponds to the current method invocation.  This is pretty easy to see why:

```
- (void)doBar:(id)bip {
  NSLog(@"hi there!")
}

- (void)doFoo {
  NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(doBar:)];
  NSInvocation *i = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
}
```

When you create the invocation in `doFoo` for the `doBar:` method, it's obvious to see that the arguments *must* be empty, because `doBar:` hasn't been executed, and thus there is no argument.  Changing `@selector(doBar:)` to `_cmd` wouldn't magically change anything.

So the next question: *is* there a way to get an `NSInvocation` for the current method invocation?  Not that I know of.  `NSInvocation` is an extremely complicated class, and constructing one from the current method would be a nightmare.

I strongly suggest finding a different approach to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks a lot for your explanation. I surely didn't understand the concept behind this :) What I did now was to use KVC a I created the member as a property. By that I could create a method that takes a string and checks if self has a value for that key. If that then was nil, I would go and try to load the prior saved object and set it as the value for the key. The idea behind this was just to have a proxy method that would internally check the member validity and read it back from file cache if needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is old and answered, here is a link that provides an easy and very elegant way to create an invocation instance for any selector/method that is known at compile time:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/construct-nsinvocation-for-any-message.html